# trying to create date returns wrong values

Tags: java, date

My java is a bit rusty, haven't used it for quite a while.

What i'm trying to do is have the user define a date (3 ints containing year, month and day) and convert this to a date object.

I have a method as follows, which is what i've ended up with after a google search

```
private double getTotalPaymentAmount(int sDay, int sMonth, int sYear, int eDay, int eMonth, int eYear)
{
    double total = 0.0;
    Iterator it = payments.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        Payment p = (Payment) pairs.getValue();
        Date d = p.getDate();
        
        Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        myCalendar.set(sYear, sMonth, sDay, 0, 0, 1);
        Date startDate = myCalendar.getTime();
        
        myCalendar.set(eYear, eMonth, eDay, 0, 0, 1);
        Date endDate = myCalendar.getTime();
        
        boolean b = startDate.compareTo(d) * d.compareTo(endDate) > 0;
        System.out.println("Start: " + startDate + " -> End: " + endDate);
        
        total = total + p.getAmount() ;
    }
    return total;
}
```

and its being called by the following, which at the moment is just being printed out

```
return " " + getTotalPaymentAmount(2014,1,1,2014,12,31);
```

The problem is the dates are completely wrong. I want the start date as 2014-01-01 and the end date as 2014-12-31 but its printing out as

> Start: Sat Aug 07 00:00:01 GMT 6 -> End: Sat Jul 06 00:00:01 GMT 37
>
> Start: Sat Aug 07 00:00:01 GMT 6 -> End: Sat Jul 06 00:00:01 GMT 37
>
> Start: Sat Aug 07 00:00:01 GMT 6 -> End: Sat Jul 06 00:00:01 GMT 37

Comment: Look at your parameter list and the argument list you are providing. Do they match semantically?

Comment: Don't forget that months go from 0 to 11.

Comment: lol, silly mistake. Though after changing it to "1,1,2014,31,12,2014" i'm getting feb 2015 and jan 2015

Comment: "Don't forget that months go from 0 to 11" didn't realise that. That'd be why i have the above problem.

Comment: Also - just for readability - instead of `startDate.compareTo(d) * d.compareTo(endDate) > 0` you could write `startDate.before(d) && endDate.after(d)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with help from Sotirios Delimanolis and David Wallace
I forgot that months start from 0 not 1, and that i had the parameters and arguments the wrong way round